# What is the error in my python script

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples, readline

I have this python script that read CSV file and  append the requested fields into  2 empty lists.

But the system display this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\readCSV.py", line 10, in <module>
  mywind.append(row[8])

builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

But when I get the type of mywind  it display list.

## code:

```
import csv
mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")
myfile.readline()
myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind=mydate=[],[]
for row in myreader:
    print(row[0],row[8])
    mywind.append(row[8])
    mydate.append(row[0])

theindex=mywind.index(max(mywind))
print(mywind[theindex],mydate[theindex])
myfile.close()
```

Comment: tuples are immutable

Comment: A tuple like this: `(5, 6, 7)` can't be modified. A list like this: `[5, 6, 7]` can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mywind=mydate=[],[]` is equivalent to `mywind = mydate = ( [] , [] )` - i.e: `mywind` and `mydate` are made equal to a tuple containing two empty lists.

```
>>> mywind = mydate = [] , []
>>> mywind
([], [])
>>> mydate
([], [])
```

I'd advise that you expand this to two lines, which is explicit:

```py
mywind = []
mydate = []
```

Using tuple assignment is "*clever*", but opens up mistakes in both writing and comprehension. If you insist, this would be correct:

```py
mywind, mydate = [], []
```

Comment: I personally prefer the "don't be clever" solution of splitting it into two lines. Tuple assignment is good for deconstruction or shuffling, but in cases like this it's just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

line 7 should read `mywind,mydate=[],[]` (observe the comma instead of equal sign).